# Putty login issue

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, putty, login

There are 2 issues -

1) when I don't set auto-login username and the radio button is set on Prompt under Connection --> Data, then also putty is by default taking system username for login Then once I enter password it gets login successfully, but Is there a way to stop taking system username and wait at login id prompt

2) when I set auto-login username or system username under Connection --> Data, then it enters login id and then auto enters login id in password field as well and results in login failure

Can you please suggest what can be the issue and if there is any specific putty setting required to be done?

Putty version being used - 0.67

Comment: I am also using Putty 0.67 but I cannot replicate this issue, is there any other changes that you may have of done?

One suggestion would be try to reinstall a new putty.exe and see if the problem arises.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. the problem was-on my machine there was a software installed which had single sign-on enabled which had cached my credentials and tried to do auto login...